# Alternative for Windows Server Task Scheduler for Linux

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, ubuntu, task-scheduler

We've been switching our server from Windows to Linux. What can we use as alternative to Windows Server Task Scheduler?

Regards,
Alexey Zakharov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 3):

It's called [crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) (click the name for a informative help page over at Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

cron
[Description](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)